# Missing labels with feynmf/feynmp?

Tags: feynmf

I am using [feynmp](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/) to generate Feynman diagrams with pdflatex.  Everything seems to be working but my labels are not showing up.

What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{feynmp}

% Needed to interpret generated *.1, *.2 etc. as ps files.
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{} 

\begin{document}
Here is a vertex for a local potential in momentum space:
\begin{fmffile}{fgraphs}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(40,30) 
    % Note that the size is given in normal parentheses instead of curly
    % brackets in units of \unitlength (default 1pt). 
    \fmfleft{i1,i2} % Define external vertices from bottom to top 
    \fmfright{o1,o2} 
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1} 
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2} 
    \fmf{photon,tension=0.3}{v1,v2}

    % These labels are missing! 
    \fmflabel{$\vec{p}$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$\vec{q}$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$\vec{p}+\vec{k}$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$\vec{p}-\vec{k}$}{o2}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Save this to `tst.tex` and compile with:

```
pdflatex tst
mpost fgraphs
pdflatex tst
pdflatex tst
```

Comment: I have removed the spacing "noise" from the MWE: It is now in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41236/automatic-spacing-with-feynmf-feynmp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the starred form `\begin{fmfgraph*}`.

Comment: This workes, but the labels are outside the bounding box and mix in with the surrounding text. Any way to work around this nicely?