# Missing labels with feynmp

Tags: feynmf

my question is exactly the same as

[Missing labels with feynmf/feynmp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41229/missing-labels-with-feynmf-feynmp?rq=1)

but the answer there did not solve my problem. I am using WinEdt 7, installed Metapost, and copy and pasted that user's code into my WinEdt. I then

1. PDFTexify
2. Opened up `fgraphs.mp` and then did Tex > MetaPost > MetaPost to generate the `fgraphs.1` file
3. Placed `\includegraphics{fgraphs.1}` into a separate tex file. When I PDFTexify, I get a diagram that has no labels.

This holds true if I change the `fmfgraph` environment to `fmfgraph*`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use `feynmp-auto` so that if you compile the .tex file with `--shell-escape` there will be no need of running metapost separately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

% Needed to interpret generated *.1, *.2 etc. as ps files.
%\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
Here is a vertex for a local potential in momentum space:
\begin{fmffile}{fgraphs}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,30)
    % Note that the size is given in normal parentheses instead of curly
    % brackets in units of \unitlength (default 1pt).
    \fmfleft{i1,i2} % Define external vertices from bottom to top
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon,tension=0.3}{v1,v2}

    % These labels are missing!
    \fmflabel{$\vec{p}$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$\vec{q}$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$\vec{p}+\vec{k}$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$\vec{p}-\vec{k}$}{o2}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To enable `--shell-escape` in winedt 7, go to `Options` → `Execution Modes` and then select `pdflatex` and type as in this figure ↓

[image]

Don't forget to press `OK` before exiting.

Comment: There should be no need of `\DeclareGraphicsRule` when `feynmp-auto` is used.

Comment: @egreg Valid point. I took the example from the linked answer and didn't take trouble to read the code as it compiled ;-) I will correct now. Thank you. :)